# Are the Collector's Edition items tradeable?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm interested in sharing the collectors edition items with a friend, is this possible or are the items linked to the collectors edition account?

Comment: There's actually an FAQ entry about this here, http://hom.guildwars2.com/en/faq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Collector's Edition of Guild Wars 2 comes with four things: the [Golem Banker](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Golem_Banker), the [Chalice of Glory](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Chalice_of_Glory), [Tome of Influence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tome_of_Influence), and the elite skill [Summon Mistfire Wolf](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Summon_Mistfire_Wolf). The skill is automatically unlocked for all your characters once you collect the items from the mail, and the others are all account bound items. Therefore, it is not possible to share the items with a friend.